# Can't generate signed apk - TaskExecutionException failed

Tags: android, proguard

I'm in the final steps of making my app live, when I try `build` and generate signed apk I get this error log from `ProGuard`

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for
>   details
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
>           at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)

This is my proguard

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keepattributes LineNumberTable,SourceFile
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
```

**Build Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.7"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you also post your build.gradle file?

Comment: updated @Artipatel

Comment: Can you delete the app build folder, clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: What app build folder ? The gradle module app?

Comment: I am talking about app->build folder

Comment: Still no changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174544/discussion-between-arti-patel-and-gaston-saillen).

Comment: Meta: please run your posts through a spelling checker before posting them; presently you're creating poorly spelled posts faster than editors can repair them. "I'm" is the correct contraction for "I am", and "Can't" is the correct contraction for "Cannot". When referring to yourself, "I" is always upper-case, no exceptions. I appreciate your first language may not be English - that's fine, but please install an English spell-checker. Any major variant of English is fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just by adding `-ignorewarnings` into the proguard did work for me. Take care that this approach is not suggested, you should fix the warnings, but this will help if you need to get your apk quick.