# How to do the or in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm new in firebase, I have difficulties in the searches

In *SQL*

```
  select * from house  where door< 2 or room=>2
```

In *firebase*

How I do it?

Comment: I hope there is no way you can do something like this. but what you can try using firebase.database().ref('house').orderByChild('door').startAt(2).endAt(2);

Comment: You could do two queries and combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this type of query with Firebase realtime database, but you can do it with Firestore.

Check [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to know how to query your data.

```
// Create a reference to door collection
CollectionReference home = db.collection("home");
// Create a query against the collection.
Query query = home.whereLessThan("door", 2);
```

And you can do the same with rooms, but you can't use the same query to query the two things together.

For all query examples, check [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/2514e09e976b65384f0255f71a7bb56303f7edd3/firestore/src/main/java/com/example/firestore/snippets/QueryDataSnippets.java#L164-L167).

Comment: Not really usefull to link a spanish documentation link :P

Comment: Hi  Gastón. I wonder if I could ask you to run your posts through an English spell-checker, in order to reduce the number of edits required on your material? The word "can't" has an apostrophe, because it is a contraction of "cannot" - the apostrophe denotes missing letters. I added [a prior reminder here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51219521).

Comment: So sorry , sometimes I just forgets , will do for further answers

Comment: No worries `:-)`. Depending on what browser you use, you may find the editor will give you a red-line underline for words that need double-checking.

Comment: Yep, but my browser and all in my PC is in Spanish, I think I'm gonna download an english plugin to autocorrect, I apologise for the errors